# Blacklisting header in Allure Rest Assured

Tags: automated-tests, testng, rest-assured, allure

I'm currently working with Allure reports to capture the results of my Rest Assured tests, and I've encountered a challenge.

Specifically, I'm having trouble filtering or blacklisting the header information. When I use the .filters(new AllureRestAssured()) method, it logs all the header details in the Allure reports.

Could someone kindly provide some guidance or insights into this issue? I would greatly appreciate any assistance you can offer.

Thank you in advance for your help.

I have created a separate class and overriding the filter method.

```
import io.restassured.filter.Filter;
import io.restassured.filter.FilterContext;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.specification.FilterableRequestSpecification;
import io.restassured.specification.FilterableResponseSpecification;

public class BlacklistHeaderFilter implements Filter {

    private final String[] blacklistedHeaders;

    public BlacklistHeaderFilter(String... blacklistedHeaders) {
        this.blacklistedHeaders = blacklistedHeaders;
    }

    @Override
    public Response filter(FilterableRequestSpecification requestSpec, FilterableResponseSpecification responseSpec, FilterContext ctx) {
        for (String header : blacklistedHeaders) {
            requestSpec.removeHeader(header);
        }
        return ctx.next(requestSpec, responseSpec);
    }
}
```

However, when I call as below as part of request secification
.filters(new AllureRestAssured())
.filters(new BlacklistHeaderFilter( "Authorization"))

The request fails as the headers get removed before making the call

Comment: This behavior is expected. To overcome this, try to override the `AllureRestAssured` class then mask the request header in log, not remove it from `requestSpec`